# Identificação de número aleatório em PHP e JSON

Tags: php, json

Estou criando um chat em PHP e JSON. NO código tenho um algoritmo que gera um número aleatório que se  transforma num arquivo .json.

Eu depois quero identificar o número random que foi gerado pelo PHP, é possível.

```
    <?php

    $rand = rand(1, 100);

$jsonword = ".json"; $file = 'json/'.$rand.$jsonword; if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $encr = json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo file_put_contents($file, $encr, FILE_APPEND);
    header('Location: index.php'); } $i = file_get_contents(/*Preciso de ajuda aqui :( */); $a = json_decode($i); ?> <!DOCTYPE html> <head> <title><?php echo $a->mensagem; ?></title> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <body> <form method="post"> <input type="text" name="mensagem" id="mensagem" placeholder="mensagem..."> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar"> </form> </body> </head>
```

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi você quer recuperar esse número gerado aleatóriamente? isso seria possivel atravez de um retorno de uma variável, utilizando - a para salvar no banco ou no arquivo para ficar de forma definitiva ou utilizar ela dentro do escopo para nao perder.

Comment: como posso fazer esse retorno?

Comment: Você guarda esse valor na variável $rand, recupere ela ou guarde a mesma em um bd, usando ela antes de terminar